# SQL query problem (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a query which selects either week 1 or week 2 or both if available and then i need to find a way of displaying only the week 1 results but knowing which ones are available for both weeks.

Here's my query which may help explain

```
select *
from table1 t1
where t1.location = 'VH' 
and (t1.week = '46' or t1.week = '47');
```

This gives me the following results

```
week    location
46      VH209A
46      VH209B
46      VH20B
46      VH20C
47      VH209B
47      VH20A
47      VH20C
```

I only want to show these results

```
week    location
46      VH209A
46      VH209B
46      VH20B
46      VH20C
```

But i want to know which records are also available for the next week i.e these ones

```
week     location
47       VH209B
47       VH20C
```

So my desired result would be something like

```
week     location    2weeks
46       VH209A        N
46       VH209B        Y
46       VH20B         N
46       VH20C         Y
```

Hope this makes sense?

Any ideas how can i get the results desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.week
  , t1.location
  , CASE WHEN t2.location is not null THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
    END AS hasmore
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT location FROM table1 WHERE week = '47') t2
  ON (t1.location = t2.location)
WHERE t1.location = 'VH' 
  AND t1.week = '46';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i seem to be getting a `missing right parenthesis` error with the `(t2.location is not null)` bit

Comment: Put a `case when` in instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered of using INNER JOIN e.g. LEFT or RIGHT JOIN ? With this you can access data from other tables which are connected to your table with the same data.

Im don't  know anything about your database structure, but I would devide several data into several tables. With this I would run a query with Joins in them.

For example

```
select * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2.withdatajoinedtotable1 ON table2.week = table1.week WHERE table2.2weeks = 'Y'
```

If you seperate your data in several tables, you can access them with JOINS.

Hope this helps.

Read more about JOINS on [SQL JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)